# Can I add a dynamic method to an existing type using System.Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, .net

I just started learning the Emit namespace - is the following valid? This throws an exception:

```
public class EmitTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        DynamicMethod dynMeth = new DynamicMethod("Foo", null, null, typeof(EmitTest));
        ILGenerator gen = dynMeth.GetILGenerator();
        gen.EmitWriteLine("Foo");
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        dynMeth.Invoke(null, null);
        dynamic d = this;
        d.Foo();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to make this work as intended or is it a limitation of DLR? Here I've created a new void method Foo() and created it as a member of the EmitTest class. The runtime says Foo() is not found on EmitTest

Comment: You said it throws an exception, what is the exception type and message?

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with the DLR.

Comment: You're right - edited title to reflect answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the `owner` parameter.
MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z84bd3st.aspx): (emphasis added)

> `owner`
>
> > A Type with which the dynamic method is **logically** associated. The dynamic method has access to all members of the type.

You cannot add methods to an existing type.

Comment: I see. A DynamicMethod is really nothing more than a delegate but has access to the members of an instance of the type it is logically associated with. I misunderstood.